# Multiattribute custom validtors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I was looking at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) on custom validators in aps.net mvc 2 and I was wondering how I might go about creating a more complex validation which worked on multiple fields at once.  Say something like

```
 if(fieldA > 7 and fieldB < 15)
```

The attribute method of creating validators doesn't seem like it would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have started using [Fleunt validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and is allows you to achieve quite complex validation with ease. While it takes some getting used to, I have found it very flexible. For example, here we make sure the length of a user password is between 7 and 15!

```
    public UserValidator() {
        RuleFor(user=> user.Password)
            .Length(7, 15)
            .WithMessage("Password to short/long");
    }
```